# How to fix multiple <div>s overlapping one another when rotated 90 degrees

Tags: html, css

I need help in rotating multiple divs and making them not overlapping one another. My simplified code is shown below:

```
<div>
    <div class="rect"></div>
    <div class="rect"></div>
    <div class="rect"></div>
 </div>
```

Styling wise:

```
.rect{
height:11cm !important;
width:15.2cm !important;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Firefox */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Opera */
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

For some reason this overlaps one another. This also make the left portion of the page empty. Is there a way to make them not overlapping, and at the same time flushed to the top left corner of the page?

Comment: You don't need -moz or -o or -webkit or -ms prefixes for transform anymore, unless you want to support really, really old browsers. 
Regarding your problem: You can set the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rotating the inner divs, you can rotate the parent div directly

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/soniaj204/pen/QXzXGJ)

```
<div class="rectwrapper">
    <div class="rect">ABCD</div>
    <div class="rect">ABCD</div>
    <div class="rect">ABCD</div>
 </div>




  .rectwrapper{

-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Firefox */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Opera */
transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: flex;
}

.rect {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  height:11cm !important;
width:15.2cm !important;

}
```

Comment: I apologize my question wasn't clear enough. I wanted the `.rect` <div>s to be aligned vertically down, instead of horizontally. A diagram is shown here: https://imgur.com/a/xcVymdF

Comment: @SamuelSmith  Check the updated codepen link - https://codepen.io/soniaj204/pen/MMZMNK